# GROUP BY clause with logical functions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle 11g Application Express, and executing these commands within the SQL Plus CLI.  This is for a class, and I cannot get past this problem.  I don't know how to add the total quantity of the items on the orders - I get confused as I don't know how to take the SUM of the QUANTITY per ORDER (customers have multiple orders).

For each customer having an order, list the customer number, the number of orders
 that customer has, the total quantity of items on those orders, and the total price for
 the items. Order the output by customer number. (Hint: You must use a GROUP BY 
 clause in this query).

Tables (we will use): 
CUSTOMER:  contains customer_num
ORDERS: contains order_num, customer_num 
ITEMS:  contains order_num, quantity, total_price

My logic:  I need to be able to calculate the sum of the quantity per order number per customer.  I have sat here for over an hour and cannot figure it out.

So far this is what I can formulate..

`SELECT customer_num, count(customer_num)
FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_num;`

I don't understand how to GROUP BY very well (yes, I have googled and researched it for a bit, and it just isn't clicking), and I have no clue how to take the SUM of the QUANTITY per ORDER per CUSTOMER.

Not looking for someone to do my work for me, just some guidance - thanks!

Comment: You're in the right direction by grouping on `customer_num`. But per the assignment, you need to group by both order and customer. Did you try something like `GROUP BY customer_num, order_num`?

Comment: Well, the way I see it - if I group by `customer_num, order_num` then it will display every order_num, and each `count(customer_num)` is only 1 when I do it this way.  The assignment calls for the `customer_num` and number of orders that customer has, hence `sum(customer_num)` - for each customer_num entry in the ORDERS table, there is an order.  I just need to know how many orders PER customer there are, and then derive the other sums from there.

Comment: One step at a time. If you need to get the sum of quantity per order per customer, you need to somehow group by `customer_num` and `order_num`, right?

Comment: Next step is that you don't need a count of customers, you need a sum of the quantities in an order. So something like `SUM(quantity)`.

Comment: I've got to have the `count(customer_num)` because every `customer_num` entry in the ORDERS table (even duplicate entries) stand for a single ORDER.  Example, customer 104 ordered something, then placed another order on a different date - `customer_num` 104 will appear in ORDERS more than once, thus constituting more than one ORDER - and I have to know the number of orders each customer has.

I tried `SUM(quantity)` -  it throws all of my numbers off.

Comment: +1 for asking for guidance, not just the answer

Comment: Ah, I see now... the assignment doesn't care about which item is in which order. Just the total number of items and the total number of orders per customer. Brian's answer below contains the logic for that. Except for the `distinct` part it is a quite literal translation of the problem description. Did you guys already cover `JOIN`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select o.customer_num,
       count(distinct o.order_num) as num_orders,
       sum(i.quantity) as total_qty,
       sum(i.total_price) as total_price
  from orders o
  join items i
    on o.order_num = i.order_num
 group by o.customer_num
 order by o.customer_num
```

First thing:
you have to join the two tables necessary to solve the problem (orders and items). The related field appears to be order_num

Second thing:
Your group by clause is fine, you want one row per customer. But because of the join to the items table, you will have to count DISTINCT orders (because there may be a one to many relationship between orders and items). Otherwise an order with 2 different associated items would be counted twice.

Next, sum the quantity and total price, you can do this now because you've joined to the needed table.

Comment: Thank you very much - This broke it down for me which is what I needed.

I was making it way more complicated than necessary - I thought I had to add the sum of the quantity PER order PER customer, which was twisting my brain in a knot.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is also solved by using `WHERE`:

```
SELECT orders.customer_num,                               /*customer number*/
       COUNT(DISTINCT orders.order_num) AS "num_orders", /*number of orders/c*/
       SUM(items.quantity) as "total_qty",               /*total quantity/c*/
       SUM(items.total_price) as "total_price"           /*total price/items*/

/* For each customer having an order, list the customer number,
the number of orders that customer has, the total quantity of items
on those orders, and the total price for the items.
Order the output by customer number.
(Hint: You must use a GROUP BY clause in this query). */

FROM orders, items
    WHERE orders.order_num = items.order_num

GROUP BY orders.customer_num
 ORDER BY orders.customer_num
;
```